# Why can't attribute names be Python keywords?

Tags: python, attributes, syntax-error

There is a restriction on the syntax of attribute access, in Python (at least in the CPython 2.7.2 implementation):

```
>>> class C(object): pass
>>> o = C()
>>> o.x = 123  # Works
>>> o.if = 123
    o.if = 123
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My question is twofold:

1. Is there a fundamental reason why using Python keyword attribute names (as in `o.if = 123`) is forbidden?
2. Is/where is the above restriction on attribute names documented?

It would make sense to do `o.class = …`, in one of my programs, and I am a little disappointed to not be able to do it (`o.class_` would work, but it does not look as simple).

**PS**: The problem is obviously that `if` and `class` are Python keywords. The question is *why* using keywords as attribute names would be forbidden (I don't see any ambiguity in the expression `o.class = 123`), and whether this is *documented*.

Comment: Because parser is simpler when keywords are always keywords, and not contextual. So the code doesn't even get to the point where there's attribute access, it's simply a syntax error on the parsing level (because `if` is part of the grammar and it never appears in this place). It's the same in most languages, and language grammar is the documentation for that.

Comment: Also, `cls` is usually used for names holding references to classes.

Comment: Even if you have a parser that's can distinguish keywords from variables/function names, it's no guarantee that one might shadow the other in a corner case. It's much easier to maintain sanity if you just straight-out forbid the use of a few dozen names.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Nice answer. Simply a design decision for efficiency of the parser. Python idiom is `if_`, `while_`, `exec_`, etc for keyword name conflicts.  `_foo` is considered a pattern for protected attributes

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: answer, not comment. You've actually *answered* it while the present answers don't answer at all.

Comment: I came across this issue using _argparse_--one of my flags was '_-or_' and using '_args.or_' caused a parsing error.

Comment: I ran into the same problem as part of argparse. I had the argument "-or" but could only access the value by using getattr().

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because parser is simpler when keywords are always keywords, and not contextual (e.g. `if` is a keyword when on the statement level, but just an identifier when inside an expression — for `if` it'd be double hard because of `X if C else Y`, and `for` is used in list comprehensions and generator expressions).

So the code doesn't even get to the point where there's attribute access, it's simply rejected by the parser, just like incorrect indentation (which is why it's a `SyntaxError`, and not `AttributeError` or something). It doesn't differentiate whether you use `if` as an attribute name, a variable name, a function name, or a type name. It can never be an identifier, simply because parser always assigns it "keyword" label and makes it a different token than identifiers.

It's the same in most languages, and language grammar (+ lexer specification) is the documentation for that. [Language spec mentions it explicitly](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers). It also doesn't change in Python 3.

Also, just because you can use `setattr` or `__dict__` to make an attribute with a reserved name, doesn't mean you *should*. Don't force yourself/API user to use `getattr` instead of natural attribute access. `getattr` should be reserved for when access to a variable attribute name is needed.

Comment: So it is how teacher tell us in compiler classes. This is how compilers are classically built. Tokens are split, classified into categories, and then analyzed if they make sense by the parser. Every special symbol like + or : has its own (unitary) category, as well as every reserved word ("if", "or", "class", "def", etc). Every other word belongs to a special category: the identifiers. Since "if" is not an identifier, it can not name an attribute, simple as that. I am not saying it is impossible to build a compiler/code analyzer in some other way, just this is how things are done these days...

Comment: @Ivella: +1 for the very relevant comment.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Agreed, about `getattr` and `__dict__`.  I was just mentioning these because they show that attributes names can be keywords even though the usual object.attribute syntax forbids it.

Comment: @EOL: It again comes down to syntax. `'if'` is always a string literal, and never a keyword. And since attributes are kept in dicts, any string will do.

Answer (score 1):

Because `if` is a keyword. You have similar issues with `o.while` and `o.for`:

```
pax> python
>>> class C(object): pass
... 

>>> o = C()

>>> o.not_a_keyword = 123

>>> o.if = 123
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    o.if = 123
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> o.while = 123
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    o.while = 123
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> o.for = 123
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    o.for = 123
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Other keywords in Python can be obtained with:

```
>>> import keyword
>>> keyword.kwlist
['and', 'as', 'assert', 'break', 'class', 'continue', 'def',
 'del', 'elif', 'else', 'except', 'exec', 'finally', 'for',
 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import', 'in', 'is', 'lambda',
 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'print', 'raise', 'return', 'try',
 'while', 'with', 'yield']
```

You should *not* generally use a keyword as variable name in Python.

I would suggest choosing a more descriptive name, such as `iface` if it's an interface, or `infld` for an input field and so forth.

As to your question edit as to *why* keywords aren't allowed, it simplifies parsers greatly if the lexical elements are context free. Having to treat the lexical token `if` as a keyword in some places and an identifier in others would introduce complexity that's not really needed if you choose your identifiers more wisely.

For example, the C++ statement:

```
long int int = char[new - int];
```

could (with a little difficulty) be evaluated with a complex parser based on where those lexical elements occur (and what exists on either side of them). But, (at least partially) in the interests of simplicity (and readability), this is not done.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I updated the title of the question so as to make explicit the fact that the question is why keywords would be forbidden as attribute names. In fact, in `o.class = 123`, it is obvious that `class` should be an attribute name; however, this is not valid (C)Python; there must be good reasons why this should not be obvious to the CPython interpreter: what are these reasons?