# How do I use a keyword as a variable name?

Tags: python, keyword

I have the following class with the variables `from`, `to` and `rate`. `from` is a [keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords). If I want to use it in the init method below, what's the correct way to write it?

More context: The class needs the `from` variable explicitly as it's part of a json required by a POST endpoint written up by another developer in a different language. So changing the variable name is out of the question.

```
class ExchangeRates(JsonAware):
    def __init__(self, from, to, rate):
        self.from = from
        self.to = to
        self.rate = rate
```

JsonAware code:

```
class PropertyEquality(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (isinstance(other, self.__class__) and self.__dict__ == other.__dict__)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(%s)' % (self.__class__.__name__, ', '.join(['%s=%s' % (k, v) for (k, v) in self.__dict__.items()]))

class JsonAware(PropertyEquality):
    def json(self):
        return json.dumps(self, cls=GenericEncoder)

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json):
        return cls(**json)
```

GenericEncoder code:

```
class GenericEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        return obj.__dict__
```

Comment: You can't use it as an identifier, because it's a keyword. That's what keyword means! Use e.g. `from_` instead.

Comment: `from` is used 3 times, and it's being flagged in red 3 times, don't I have to escape they keyword or something using **kwargs?

Comment: You could do it that way if you like: `setattr(self, 'from', kwargs.get('from'))`, but then you have to pass it in via a dictionary too: `rates = ExchangeRates(..., **{'from': whatever})` and can only access it via `getattr(rates, 'from')`. It's **much** less awkward to rename it. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/9746838/3001761

Comment: flagged in red sounds like an IDE trying to assist the author ;-) I would follow @jonrsharpe's advice.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - the `from` variable is part of the json used to hit a POST endpoint written up by someone else on the team using a different language. I wanted to find out if it was not possible for me to handle it using python before getting them to change the variable name, will get them to change it regardless :) Should this question be closed? Or could you post a quick answer?

Comment: You could expand the question with that context and a [mcve] (what's `JsonAware`?), there are probably ways to handle parsing to and from JSON where the keys are keywords. But you definitely can't do it directly.

Comment: Never try to trick compiler/interpreter, it will haunt you back!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `from` is a Python keyword so you can't use it as a variable name, or an attribute name. So you need to use an alternative name, and do a conversion when reading or writing the JSON data.

To do the output conversion you can supply a new encoder for `json.dumps`; you can do that by overriding the `ExchangeRates.json` method. To do the input conversion, override `ExchangeRates.from_json`.

The strategy is similar in both cases: we create a copy of the dictionary (so we don't mutate the original), then we create a new key with the desired name and value, then delete the old key.

Here's a quick demo, tested on Python 2.6 and 3.6:

```
import json

class PropertyEquality(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (isinstance(other, self.__class__) and self.__dict__ == other.__dict__)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(%s)' % (self.__class__.__name__, ', '.join(['%s=%s' % (k, v) for (k, v) in self.__dict__.items()]))

class JsonAware(PropertyEquality):
    def json(self):
        return json.dumps(self, cls=GenericEncoder)

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json):
        return cls(**json)

class ExchangeRatesEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        d = obj.__dict__.copy()
        d['from'] = d['frm']
        del d['frm']
        return d

class ExchangeRates(JsonAware):
    def __init__(self, frm, to, rate):
        self.frm = frm
        self.to = to
        self.rate = rate

    def json(self):
        return json.dumps(self, cls=ExchangeRatesEncoder)

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json):
        d = json.copy()
        d['frm'] = d['from']
        del d['from']
        return cls(**d)

# Test

a = ExchangeRates('a', 'b', 1.23)
print(a.json())

jdict = {"from": "z", "to": "y", "rate": 4.56, }

b = ExchangeRates.from_json(jdict)
print(b.json())
```

**typical output**

```
{"from": "a", "to": "b", "rate": 1.23}
{"from": "z", "to": "y", "rate": 4.56}
```

Comment: Other languages, such as C#, work around this using the `@` symbol, e.g. `@string`. It would be nice to have that in python, e.g. `@lambda`.

Comment: @EduardoPignatelli In Python, the `@` symbol is used to create a function or class [decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator). The [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id36) convention for names that clash with reserved words or builtin names is to append a single trailing underscore, as mentioned in Psionman's answer.

Comment: The `@` symbol is arbitrary, it can really be anything. The problem I find with the underscore is that it actually modifies the name of the variable (i.e. it will end with the underscore).

Answer (score 9):

Add a single underscore to your preferred names. In this instance: from_ (Note thanks to @Karl Knechtel 'to' is not keyword)

(see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles))

```
class ExchangeRates(JsonAware):
    def __init__(self, from_, to, rate):
        self.from = from_
        self.to = to
        self.rate = rate
```

[Edit remove 'to_']

Comment: This is wrong: `to` isn't reserved, and attributes also need to be decorated in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Use a synonym. Try "origin" or "source" instead.