# The `object.from` attribute

Tags: python

I have stumbled upon the following syntax error with my Python3 interpreter:

```py
class Class:
    pass

a = Class()
a.from = 2
```

```
    a.from = 2
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Assignment of attributes that do not contain `.from` seem to be working fine:

```py
a = Class()
a.fro = 2
print(a.__dict__)
```

```
{'fro': 2}
```

I understand that the standalone `from` statement is reserved for imports but struggle to understand why that would matter in the context of a class with the same key in its dict. Can someone explain why the interpreter complains at this point?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use a keyword as a variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968516/how-do-i-use-a-keyword-as-a-variable-name)

Answer (score 1):

Simply because it's a reserved keyword that you can't use as an identifier.

The same issue would arise with e. g. `x.in`, `x.for`, `x.import`,...