# Sort dictionary, then sort it with another

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I sorted according to points (just numbers). If two points in the dictionary are equal I want to take another dictionary with the same keys but other numbers (goals). So when the points are equal I want to sort the two equal elements so that the one with more goals stands before the other one with less goals but equal points. This must not affect the other elements in the list which have different points.

Here is the code for now:

```
import random
sorted_dict = {}
dict = {"t": 5, "m": 3, "s": 4, "d": 8}
dict_keys_points_2 = []
dict_keys_points = dict.keys()

for element in dict_keys_points:
    dict_keys_points_2.append(element)

sorted_values = sorted(dict.values(), reverse=True)

for i in sorted_values:
    for k in dict_keys_points_2:
        if dict[k] == i:
            sorted_dict[k] = dict[k]
            dict_keys_points_2.remove(k)
            break
dict_points = {}
dict_keys_unsorted = dict.keys()
a = sorted_dict.keys()
for element in a:
    dict_keys.append(element)
for element in dict_keys:
    dict_points[element] = random.randint(0, 5)
```

output:

```py
{'d': 2, 't': 4, 's': 0, 'm': 4} #(the goals)  
{'d': 8, 't': 5, 's': 4, 'm': 3} #(the points)
```

so if there are two elements with the same points, I'd like to look at the goals and sort the two elements:
i.e:

```py
{'d': 8, **'t': 5, 's': 5,** 'm': 3} #<-- two same points
{'d': 2, **'t': 0**, **'s': 4,** 'm': 4} #<-- s has more goals 
#so after that the dictionary should look like this:
{'d': 8, **'s'**: 5, **'t'**: 5, 'm': 3}
```

Comment: Currently the question is a bit ambiguous, could you provide some sample inputs and their respective outputs?

Comment: Avoid using `dict` as variable name.

Comment: Don’t use keyword to istantiate variables or objects. Change dict to something else.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968516/how-do-i-use-a-keyword-as-a-variable-name

Comment: ok it was only a test page in my actual code there is another name

Comment: Where is this other dictionary with the same keys but other numbers (goals) in the code in your question? Please provide code that matches the description of what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can create a new dict with points and goals as a tuple of 'values' in the dict. I can then use normal sorting on these 'values'. If there is a collision in the first value, the second value from the tuple (i.e., goals) will be used for sorting it.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

goals = {'d': 2, 't': 4, 's': 8, 'm': 4}
points = {'d': 8, 't': 5, 's': 5, 'm': 3}

new_dict = {k: (v, goals[k]) for k, v in points.items()}
# new_dict = {'d': (8, 2), 't': (5, 4), 's': (5, 8), 'm': (3, 4)}

sorted_list = sorted(new_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
# sorted_list = [('d', (8, 2)), ('s', (5, 8)), ('t', (5, 4)), ('m', (3, 4))]

# Discard the goals from the values tuple to get the original, but sorted dict.
sorted_dict = OrderedDict([(i[0], i[1][0]) for i in sorted_list])
# OrderedDict([('d', 8), ('s', 5), ('t', 5), ('m', 3)])
```