# type object 'Album' has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and web coding.

I'm following Bucky tuts: Django Tutorial for Beginners - 29 - Generic Views

& I'm trying to get my music ( index ) page , but it gives me that error in the browser :

> AttributeError at /music/  type object 'Album' has no attribute
>   'object'

& here's my views.py :

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render , get_object_or_404
from .models import Album,song
from django.views import generic

"""
def index(request):
    all_albums = Album.objects.all()
    context = {'all_albums': all_albums}
    return render(request, 'music/index.html', context)
"""

class IndexView (generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'music/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_albums'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Album.object.all()

'''
class DetailView (generic.DetailView):
    model = Album
    template_name = "music/details.html"
'''


def details(request, album_id):
    try:
        album = Album.objects.get(pk=album_id)
    except Album.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Album Does Not Exists !")
    return render(request, 'music/details.html', {'album': album})

def favourite (request , album_id):
    album = get_object_or_404 (Album , pk=album_id)
    try:
        selected_song = album.song_set.get(pk=request.POST['song'])
    except(KeyError, song.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'music/details.html', {
            'album':album,
            'error_message': "you entered wrong"
        })
    else:
        selected_song.is_favorite = False
        selected_song.save()


        return render(request,'music/details.html' , {'album':album})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Album (models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title + " - " + self.artist


class song (models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    is_favourite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'music/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Main : MuSiC {% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<ul>
    {% for album in all_albums %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'music:details' album.id %}">{{ album.album_title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}

#/music/{{ album.id }}
```

project structure

```
{ (website) project dir }
|-music
..|-migrations
..|-static
..|-templates
....|-music
......|-base.html
......|-details.html
......|-index.html
|-__init__.py
|-admin.py
|-apps.py
|-models.py
|-tests.py
|-urls.py
|-views.py
|-website
..|-__init__.py
..|-settings.py
..|-urls.py
..|-wsgi.py
|-db.sqlite3
|-manage.py
```

and I don't know where is the problem :(

btw, lot's of coding terms I still didn't learned , that's why I may ask alot ever I searched for a solution but didn't understand the answer from other question's answers .

Comment: somewhere in your codes, you put `Album.object` instead of `Album.objects`

Comment: check the answer of @wpercy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Album.object` does not exist; you should've written `Album.objects`.

```
class IndexView (generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'music/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_albums'

    def get_queryset(self):
        # return Album.object.all()  <-- Remove this
        return Album.objects.all()
```

As a side note, reserved words cannot be python attributes.  This is by design, because disallowing these words makes parsing substantially easier.

[Why can't attribute names be Python keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746838/why-cant-attribute-names-be-python-keywords)