# How to validate JSON field with name "from"

Tags: python, json, telegram-bot, pydantic

I want to validate JSON object (it is in [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message)) which contains **from** field (which is reserved word in Python) by using [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io) validator. So my model should look like the following:

```
class Message(BaseModel):
  message_id: int
  from: Optional[str]
  date: int
  chat: Any
  ...
```

But using **from** keyword is not allowed in this context.

How could I do this?

**Note:** this is *different* than "Why we can't use keywords as attributes" because here we get external JSON we don't control and we anyway should handle JSON with **from** field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't attribute names be Python keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746838/why-cant-attribute-names-be-python-keywords)

Comment: The proposed duplicate says *why* you can't use `from` as an attribute, not how you would work around that here to accommodate a JSON object using `from` as a key.

Comment: One way that *may* work (probably not the "right" way to do it) is to update the annotations yourself: `Message.__annotations__.update({'from': Optional[str]})`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I [believe](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/153) you can replace `from` with `from_`.

You can do it like this:

```
class Message(BaseModel):
    message_id: int
    from_: Optional[str]
    date: int
    chat: Any

    class Config:
        fields = {
        'from_': 'from'
        }
    ...
```

Comment: and to get data after validation

`valid_data = Message(data).dict(by_alias=True)`

Answer (score 2):

There might be a way to do this using a `class` statement, but I didn't see anything in a quick skim of the documentation. What you could do is use dynamic model creation instead.

```
fields = {
    'message_id': (int,),
    'from': (Optional[str], ...),
    'date': (int, ...),
    'chat': (Any, ...)
 }
 Message = create_model("Message", **fields)
```